# Select2-removed event not getting fired?

Tags: jquery-select2-4

I'm using select2 4.0.0, and I want to get the val of an item removed, to do this I'm trying use the event select2-removed but it doesn't works, it doesn't execute.

How could I do this ?

trying.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectedItems').on('select2-removed', function (e) {
        console.log(e.val);
    }).select2({
        placeholder: "Select an option"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found exactly what I wanted

I did

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectedItems')
        .on('select2:unselect', function (e) {
            console.log(e.params.data.id);
        })        
        .select2({
            placeholder: "Select an option"
    }   );

});
```